# How to write binary data into a serial port (RS232) device file in linux?

Tags: linux, device

I'm doing a project in linux for which i need to write binary data into the device file of serial port (RS232) port. when i write the file into serial port (RS232), a RF transmitter connected to this port must send signal to RF receivers situated at different places.

The data to written is in a user created file.I have to just copy the data from that file and write into the device file whenever user wants(say a button click in java interface)

I have googled but couldn't get much of the information and some i couldn't understand.What is the simplest way to do this using shell script.(C program will work too)

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, for example:

```
cat file.bin > /dev/ttyPS0
```

- `file.bin` is binary file,
- `/dev/ttyPS0` is device representing serial port.

Note: use `stty` to configure serial port appropriately.

Comment: Yes, that's a literal answer.  But the port likely needs to be configured first.

Comment: would you need superuser permission to run above command ? @Chris Stratton

Comment: You won't need su privilege if your user is added to the same group that the port belongs to. For example, some devices are owned by `dialout`. (at least this is the case for Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: can i write data from any other file (Eg. text file) to device file? @superdesk